# How to make function wait for map() execution in react

Tags: javascript, wait

I have this function `createOrder()` that depends on the following `map()` function

```
 const [rowsData, setRowsData] = useState([
    {
      width: { width: "", error: false },
      height: { height: "", error: false },
      quantity: { quantity: "", error: false },
    },
  ]);

const [final, setFinal] = useState([]);

const process = (value) => {
    let newData;
    rowsData.map((item, index) => {
      newData = {
        width: item.width.width,
        height: item.height.height,
        quantity: item.quantity.quantity,
      };
      setFinal([...final, newData]);
    });
createOrder(final)
  };
/* The Button */
 <Button onClick={() => process(rowsData)}>Submit</Button>
```

The idea is that i get values from fields `rowsData` then put them in a final data field `final`. After i call the `createOrder` function with the `final` array as parameter

The `createOrder` function is a simple `setState` on another object

```
const [order, setOrder] = useState({
    material: "",
    materialType: "",
    provider: "",
    item: "",
  });

const createOrder = (value) => {
let item = { ...order, item: value };
setOrder(item);
}
```

When i use my method the `item` field is empty. How do i make `createOrder` wait for the map function?

Comment: Why not just use the result from `rowsData.map()`? Instead of appending to `final` in each iteration, just make the map callback function return the constructed object. Then `rowsData.map()` would return an array of objects, which you can then pass into `createOrder`

Comment: @LawrenceWebDev rowsData is an array of objects(example [{width: 1, height: 1 quantity: 1}, {width: 1, height: 1 quantity: 1}] 
How can i add it to order object in item field?

Comment: But you’re currently already passing `final` into `createOrder`, and `final` would be an array of objects.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention the reason is i used rowsData also as error checker (example:  width: { width: "", error: false }) in my form but i will edit it to only use the data instances.
thank you for the help!

Comment: It's not the `.map()` that you have to await for - map is fully synchronous. You need to wait for `setFinal()` which gets batch processed later by React. Assuming that `final` is a state variable, the correct way to wait for it is to use a `useEffect()` hook. And yes, I know it means that `process()` will return before everything is done but that's how React works. Basically you need to remove `createOrder()` from `process()` and `useEffect(() => createOrder(final)),[final])` - what this line does is call `createOrder` when final gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

It's not `map()` that you need to wait for. `Array.prototype.map` is fully synchronous and don't need/can't be waited on. What you are waiting for is `setFinal()` to actually update `final`. State variables/functions are asynchronous in React.

Taking a cue from LawrenceWebDev you really should update `final` in a single shot to avoid multiple updates.. even though in theory it should not be necessary because React should batch those updates. Remember, the updates to `final` is asynchronous, to calling `setFinal()` does not update `final`, calling `setFinal()` and waiting a short time will update `final`:

```
const process = (value) => {
  let newData;
  let newFinal = rowsData.map((item, index) => {
    return {
      width: item.width.width,
      height: item.height.height,
      quantity: item.quantity.quantity,
    }
  });
  setFinal(newFinal);
};
```

Now to call `createOrder()` you need to wait for `final` to be updated:

```
useState(() => createOrder(final), [ final ]);
```